# EventStore build.cmd Errors

Tags: cqrs, neventstore

Just getting started with JOlivers event store library and having issues with some of the Nuget commands in the build.cmd.  here's the log, perhaps you're already aware of the issue but i thought i'd put it up here.

```
=== COMPILING ===
Compiling / Target: v4.0 / Config: Release
S:\SourceControl\Test Projects\EventStore\bin\nuget\NuGet.targets(6,9): error : Input string was not in a correct format. [S:\SourceControl\Test Projects\EventStore\src\proj\EventStore.Persistence.RavenPersistence\EventStore.Persistence.RavenPersistence.csproj]
S:\SourceControl\Test Projects\EventStore\bin\nuget\NuGet.targets(6,9): error MSB3073: The command ""S:\SourceControl\Test Projects\EventStore\src\..\bin\nuget\nuget.exe" install "S:\SourceControl\Test Projects\EventStore\src\proj\EventStore.Persistence.RavenPersistence\packages.config" -source "" -o "S:\SourceControl\Test Projects\EventStore\src\..\bin"" exited with code 1. [S:\SourceControl\Test Projects\EventStore\src\proj\EventStore.Persistence.RavenPersistence\EventStore.Persistence.RavenPersistence.csproj]
```

Comment: Seriously, can do read this, [edit] your question, snip out only the important parts, and format it so that its readable?

Comment: I'm doing a clean build on the master branch and it's working great.  But then again, I don't have any spaces in my paths.

Answer (score 0):

The master branch of EventStore appears to be broken at the moment.  The 3.0 branch is in better shape but is also slightly broken.  To fix the 3.0 branch so that it builds, you need to upgrade the 1.5 version of nuget.exe to 1.6.  The easiest way to do that is to execute `\bin\nuget\NuGet.exe update -self` in the repository.  I already submitted a pull request to JOliver with that change.

(I also submitted a pull request with a few minor fixes for the example project.)